unbounded sequence - tail recursion
I want to create an unbounded sequence and wondered if i could do it via a tail recursive function.
a simple example being
<xsl:function name="kooks:repeat" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="kooks:repeat()"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="kooks:repeat()[5]"/>
</xsl:template>

(I'm using Saxon-ee 11.4)
This fails with
Severity: error
Description: class java.lang.StackOverflowError


I think the issue is because there are 2 sequence statements then saxon interprets this as a append/cons operation and thus the function is no longer tail recursive (in its model).
If we compare this to the F# code (which is what I'm trying to translate into XSLT)
let rec ones () =
    seq {
        yield 1
        yield! ones ()
    }

let tenMillionthEntry = 
    ones ()
    |> Seq.skip 10000000
    |> Seq.take 1
    |> Seq.head

this doesn't consider the consecutive yield, yield! as an operation in the function and so its tail recursion optimisation works (presumably as this code doesnt blow up).

Is that approach taken from some other declarative/function programming language? I sure would expect something like Saxon gives "Too many nested function calls. May be due to infinite recursion". Do you expect the recursion to stop as you only select the fifth item in the sequence?

it all depends on how 'sequence' behaves, and actually the spec doesnt say, in some languages this would crash, and in others it wouldnt. in Haskell you would write something like
ones = 1 : ones
(that may be wrong, but its the same idea)

saxon allows streamable output, so I would expect it, at some level, to work like this

actually I MAY have worked out how to do this, in a very clunky way, I'll post the answer if it works

no....i got half way, but as soon as I add parameters then it effectively fails, I cant see how to force tail recursion.

I think XPath 4 has a so far open feature issue for generators.

not sure, i took part in some of those comments, fundamentally I'm trying to create a sequence 'unfold' function, this (IMO) should be primitive in the language, and it seems quite trivky to write your own

Sorry, you CAN write it, but unless its tail recursive it will cause issues, I was hoping to write something that generated unbounded sequences and is tail recursive as the first step, and then introduce the 'unfolder' into it

See an implementation of a Generator for this - in my answer. A generator is a map, thus it is a function. It is not tail-recursive, but using it to generate many of its items does not lead to stack overflow - my guess is that BaseX has a reasonable garbage-collection policy. So, taking either the 10M-th or the 50M-th item works correctly.

Christian Grün on the XML slack came up with something along the following lines:
let $inf-rec := function($start, $self) {
      map {
        'skip': function($c) { $self($start + $c, $self) },
        'take': function($c) { $start to $start + $c - 1 }
      }
    },
    $inf := function() {
      $inf-rec(1, $inf-rec)
    }
return $inf()?skip(10000000)?take(1) ! head(.)

XPath 3.1 example online.
He also said in XPath 4.0 there are functions https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-do-until and https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-while-do that could help.
Also wait whether Dimitre Novatchev shows up to explain his ideas for infinite sequences in XPath 4.

ah, I've just put a demonstration of a lazylist on the generator proposal, I can create unbound lazylists, but I cant 'serialise' them into a sequence (well I can, but not tail recursively)

I'll take a look at this though, maybe this will help me do what I want more directly

ah...I think this is "cheating"....it does actually do what the question says but it wont allow me to 'introduce' and unfolder function, because its wired into the correlation between the index and number at that index.

@MrDatKookerellaLtd, I posted the suggestion by Christian as one way, I agree it is not a full implementation of your requirements but I thought it worth sharing. I also said to wait for Dimitre who has shown up by now and posted his XPath 3.1 generator code so it is hopefully more generic than the code here. It is unfortunately failing with various versions of Saxon (Saxon Java, SaxonCS, SaxonC) for higher values passed in, the threshhold seems to depend on the implementation and the platform, SaxonC under Linux manages 12000 but not 13000, Saxon J under Windows doesn't even manage the 1000

@MartinHonnen Hopefully Saxon will be improved in the future. We do have BaseX, which successfully works for N = 10M, 50M, 100M ...  Seems like everything one could want ... :)

@MartinHonnen I've seen dimitre's code on the w3c spec issues page, its equivalent to the code I was forced to write.

@MrDatKookerellaLtd :  What you are complaining about... If you feel uncomfortable using XPath, then simply don't use it. Finding something equivalent to your F#/Haskell code is great. And saying that you were "forced to write" some code... who forces you? As an example - for a very long time I haven't noticed C# programmers complain about the weirdness of Java code - people are happy using C# and don't want to teach Java programmers how they should write their code, or what features Java must or shouldn't have. And of course - happy C# programmers don't even think of writing Java code.

I was forced to write it because XPath/XSLT doesnt allow lazy generation/unfold, I believe thats why you have the generator proposal? You were forced to propose it because it didnt exist?

@DimitreNovatchev - apologies, I wanst implying you or your code had forced me, simply the lack of this functionality.

@MrDatKookerellaLtd Re: "You were forced to propose it because it didn't exist?" Not  because it didn't exist, but because this was a very interesting idea and I like imagining and implementing challenging concepts.

@MrDatKookerellaLtd Mark, I think this discussion will also be interesting for you: https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/670

ah, there's quite a lot there, i would have to dig into it and probably translate it to languages I am more at ease with before I could comment.

@MrDatKookerellaLtd, Not a problem - it is just quite related to this current SO question, and I have provided there what I think could be a substantial definition of "Lazy Processing" - generators plus providing short-circuiting hints to foldr.

If I understand the problem, you want to get the Nth item from a possibly infinite sequence of items.
There is a proposal on qtspecs for the Generator datatype.
When this will be provided in XPath 4.0, the solution will be just this one-liner:
$gen1ToInf?at(10000000)
where $gen1ToInf is a generator for the infinite sequence of natural numbers.
Here is the XPath 3.1 expression of this - where all these standard generator functions have been implemented in XPath 3.1:
let $put := function($map as map(*), $key as xs:anyAtomicType, $value as item()*) as map(*)
             { Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map}put($map, $key, $value) },
     $gen1ToInf :=
       map{
            "initialized": true(),
            "endReached": false(),
            "getCurrent": function($this as map(*)) { $this?last + 1},
            "moveNext":  function($this as map(*))
                         {
                           if(not($this?initialized)) then $put($this, "initialized", true())
                             else $put($this, "last", $this?last +1)
                         },
            "last" : 0 
           },
   $emptyGenerator := function()
   {
       map{
           "initialized" : true(),
           "endReached": true(),
           "getCurrent": function($this as map(*)) {error()},
           "moveNext": function($this as map(*)) {error()}
          }     
   },
   
   $skip-helper := function($gen as map(*), $n as xs:integer, $self as function(*))
   {
       if($n eq 0) then $gen
         else
         (
             let $gen := if(not($gen?initialized)) then $gen?moveNext()
                           else $gen
               return
                 if(not($gen?endReached)) then $self($gen?moveNext($gen), $n -1, $self)
                   else $gen
       )     
   },
   $skip := function($gen as map(*), $n as xs:integer)
   {
      $skip-helper($gen, $n, $skip-helper)
   },
   
   $take-helper := function($gen as map(*), $n as xs:integer, $self as function(*))
   {
    let $gen := if(not($gen?initialized)) then $gen?moveNext()
                        else $gen
        return
           if( $gen?endReached or $n eq 0) then $emptyGenerator()
              else $put($gen, "moveNext", $self($gen?moveNext($gen), $n -1, $self))
   },
   
   $take := function($gen as map(*), $n as xs:integer)
   {
     $take-helper($gen, $n, $take-helper)
   },
   
   $subrange := function($gen as map(*), $m as xs:integer, $n as xs:integer) as map(*)
   {
     $take($skip($gen, $m -1), $n)
   },
   
   $at := function($gen as map(*), $ind as xs:integer)
   {
     let $genResult :=$subrange($gen, $ind, 1)
      return
       $genResult?getCurrent($genResult)
   }
   return
     $at($gen1ToInf, 10000000)

And sure enough, this works without a problem:


as discussed, this is basically where i ended up, but using unfold, rather than a "generator".

There is no "unfold" in XPath, and this is an XPath question. Please, in the future tag your questions better.

The question is in terms of XSLT, your solution is in XPath, I see no problem with the tag.
